# CSS maintain div aspect ratio given height

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've found many responses that answer this question given a width. For example:
[Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-maintain-div-aspect-ratio)

But if I need to set

```
div{
  position: absolute
  bottom: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  padding-right: 125%;
}
```

those solutions do not work.

How can I maintain the div's aspect ratio when I have the height set as above?

Comment: You tried using calc() in your css? for example: height: calc(width * 1.25)

Comment: try adding `position: relative` to your div

Comment: Try setting height and width relative to the `vh` units (1/100th of viewport height) like this:  `width: 40vh; height: 30vh;`. I am assuming that it's the height of the viewable area that you're concerned with, not the entire height of a web page.

Comment: where have you set the width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using viewport units. Depending on your audience, this may or may not be the best solution. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units for details. Also, depending on the aspect ratio you want, it will go off the screen  in some cases. My next suggestion would bring JavaScript into the mix.

Here's a fiddle you can try out: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7v2gcq/

And the important code:

```
#vhtest {
    position: relative;
    top: 5vh;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 50vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```